# Can we change the constructor behavior using typescript class decorators? I mean to change number of parameters in constructor

Tags: typescript

**typescript code**

```
@logClass // this is my decorator
class Person { 

  public name: string;
  public surname: string;

  constructor(name : string, surname : string) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }
}
function logClass(target: any) {

  // save a reference to the original constructor
  var original = target;

  // a utility function to generate instances of a class
  function construct(constructor, args) {
    var c : any = function () {
      return constructor.apply(this, args);
    }
    c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return new c();
  }

  // the new constructor behaviour
  var f : any = function (...args) {
    console.log("New: " + original.name); 
    return construct(original, args);
  }

  // copy prototype so intanceof operator still works
  f.prototype = original.prototype;

  // return new constructor (will override original)
  return f;
}
```

in the above code the new constructor adds an extra `console.log();`. But I also want to change the number of parameters passed to the constructor. Is it possible? Or can we add any other behavior? If so, please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the arguments which are passed to the original constructor.

Removing args:

```
var f : any = function (...args) {
    const level = args.shift();
    console[level]("New: " + original.name);
    return construct(original, args);
}
...
new Person("debug", "name", "othername");
```

Adding args:

```
var f : any = function (...args) {
    console.log("New: " + original.name);
    if (args.length == 1) {
        args.push("othername");
    }
    return construct(original, args);
}
...
new Person("name");
```

The problem with this approach though is that it's not clear from the constructor signature what will actually happen, someone who reads it might think that the ctor accepts two arguments but since the decorator changes that things will break at runtime.

---

#### Edit

No, you cannot change the signature of a constructor (or any method/function) using a decorator because those are static and being checked when complied, but the decorators can only change things at runtime.

My answer about adding/removing arguments for the ctor are done at runtime, meaning that while the declared ctor for person is:

```
constructor(name : string, surname : string)
```

Then doing this:

```
var f : any = function (...args) {
    const level = args.shift();
    console[level]("New: " + original.name);
    return construct(original, args);
}
```

Creates a new **runtime** ctor that has the following signature:

```
constructor(level: string, name : string, surname : string)
```

It then (again, at runtime) removes the first element in the args, use it as the level for `console` and then calls the old ctor (the old declared signature) with just the two args as it expects.

Comment: Could you please explain me in detail?

Comment: I did not do much, it's exactly what you did just that I either removed elements from the `args` array (using `shift`) or added elements to the `args`. Since this `args` array is then used as the constructor parameters then doing so changes the params passed to the ctor as you asked for.

Comment: No. It's not working. I am getting error after creating new object.
`new Person("debug", "name", "othername");` or `new Person("name");` these lines are the error lines. Because the supplied parameters do not match with the constructor signature.

Comment: Even pushing elements to the args will not be worked if we push more than one element.

Comment: I want only one thing that is the class decorators will change the behavior of constructor. Please justify it with your answer.

Comment: Wait, you want to change the signature of the constructor so that you'll be able to write code like `new Person("debug", "name", "othername");`?

Comment: Yup. Can we change the signature of the ctor?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Check my revised answer.