# Class Decorator in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I'm trying to understand how class decorators work in Typescript when we wish to replace the constructor. I've seen this demo:

```
const log = <T>(originalConstructor: new(...args: any[]) => T) => {
    function newConstructor(... args) {
        console.log("Arguments: ", args.join(", "));
        new originalConstructor(args);
    }
    newConstructor.prototype = originalConstructor.prototype;
    return newConstructor;
}

@log
class Pet {
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {}
}

new Pet("Azor", 12);
//Arguments: Azor, 12
```

Everything is understood but this line:

```
newConstructor.prototype = originalConstructor.prototype;
```

Why do we do that?

Comment: Let's start with the fact that your code doesn't really do what you think it does. It doesn't work. Change the ctor to `constructor(public name: string, public age: number)` and then try to access the instance members (`name` and `age`) and you'll get `undefined`. Check this question for the right way of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198811/can-we-change-the-constructor-behavior-using-typescript-class-decorators-i-mean

Comment: Hi,

This code is from the internet, I don't care if it works I just need to know why we need this line because I've seen it in more examples

Answer (score 3):

The classes like:

```
class Pet {
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {}
    dosomething() {
        console.log("Something...");
    }
}
```

Are compiled into functions when targeting ES5:

```
var Pet = (function () {
    function Pet(name, age) {
    }
    Pet.prototype.dosomething = function () {
        console.log("Something...");
    };
    return Pet;
}());
```

As you can seem when we use functions to define classes. The methods are added to the function's prototype.

This means that if you are going to create a new constructor (new function) you need to copy all the methods (the prototype) from the old object:

```
function logClass(target: any) {

  // save a reference to the original constructor
  const original = target;

  // a utility function to generate instances of a class
  function construct(constructor: any, args: any[]) {
    const c: any = function () {
      return constructor.apply(this, args);
    };
    c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return new c();
  }

  // the new constructor behaviour
  const newConstructor: any = function (...args: any[]) {
    console.log("New: " + original.name);
    return construct(original, args);
  };

  // copy prototype so intanceof operator still works
  newConstructor.prototype = original.prototype;

  // return new constructor (will override original)
  return newConstructor;
}
```

You can learn more at ["Decorators & metadata reflection in TypeScript: From Novice to Expert (Part I)"](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript)

### Update

Please refer to https://github.com/remojansen/LearningTypeScript/tree/master/chapters/chapter_08 for a more recent version.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being `ES5` or not. The same is true in `ES6` as well

Comment: Throws error. The answer's code sample is taken from an old source (2015).
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` in reference to the prototype assignment step. I don't think there's an easy way to copy the prototype. I want to be able to code it clearly and concisely without mutating the original reference to the constructor prototype :(.

Comment: This code has now a good few months. For a more recent version please refer to https://github.com/remojansen/LearningTypeScript/tree/master/chapters/chapter_08